# Group with two elements, show that $a = b = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that a group $G$ contains two elements $a$ and $b$, where $a^{−1}ba = b^2$ and $b^{−1}ab = a^2$. Suppose also that every element of $G$ can be expressed as a product of the elements $a$, $b$, $a^{−1}$ and $b^{−1}$, taken as often as we wish, in any order, and with repetitions allowed. Show that $a = b = e$ and hence that $G = \{e\}$.

I don't really understand the question completely (because I just started chapter on groups). Could somebody guide me what should I do to solve the problem.

Comment: In mathematics, and I think this especially applies to introductory group theory, sometimes a problem can be solve by formal manipulation. You can see this in the answer below. One really needs to "play around" in order to figure out what is what. The more you do this, the better you'll get at it. Just a warning: sometimes things will follow from formal manipulation, but they may also have a deeper explanation for what is going on. In such a case the latter is preferable, so don't get too caught up in formal manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**let's develop the user1's hint:** *(since it's not a homework and the OP  just started chapter on groups)*

Since $a^{−1}ba = b^2$ so $ba=ab^2$ and since $b^{−1}ab = a^2$ we have $ab=ba^2$ so we find $ba=ab^2=(ab)b=ba^2b$ so by canceling we have $ab=e$ so $b=a^{-1}$. Now from the first equality we have $a=b=e$.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the way we call it [Van Kampen diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram) for finding the magic relation $b^{-1}=a$. Here is that approach:

[image]

Via gray area you can read $$\overrightarrow{a~a~b~a^{-1}}=1$$ which is $a=b^{-1}$.

Comment: Sweet way to approach the problem!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Using the given equations, find formulas for $ba$ and $ab$. Substitute the formula for one in the formula for the other.